# How to check if a path resolves to an entry in package.json#exports?

Tags: node.js, eslint

For context, I am writing an [eslint](/questions/tagged/eslint) rule.

The ESLint rule needs to determine if the import path requires `.js` extension or not, e.g.

```
import '@contra/utilities/safeStringify';
```

In this case, `@contra/utilities` `package.json` contains an entry in `exports` for this sub-path:

```json
"exports": {
  ".": "./dist/index.js",
  "./safeStringify": "./dist/safeStringify.js"
},
```

Therefore, the `.js` extension is not needed.

However, these patterns can be a lot more complicated, e.g.

```json
"exports": {
  ".": "./dist/index.js",
  "./*": "./dist/*.js"
},
```

Therefore, I am trying to figure out if there is a native [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) method to check if an import path resolves to an entry in `package.json#exports`.